# Date not show in JSQMessageViewcontroller Chat page

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

```
messageForRow = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"UserId"] senderDisplayName:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] date:[NSDate distantPast] text: [[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Message"]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ld need to implement these methods to make it visible

```
  - (NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];//22-Nov-2012
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] date]];
        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:formattedDateString];
     }

    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView
                       layout:(JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout heightForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return kJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellLabelHeightDefault;
    }
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14779a00'

Comment: Sorry we need to feed string for NSAttributedString constructor. See my edit